Quickest way of displaying large text in android app
I have written an app which downloads a large txt file using Java URL and BufferedInputStream. The file downloads quite fast in around 4 seconds for a 20 - 30Mb file. The file is actually logs. While reading the file in line by line the data is stored in an ArrayList of String.
I then traverse through the ArrayList and build a TableLayout with rows and textviews for each line. However this process takes forever (more than 8 minutes) to finally complete and update the UI.
Is there a quicker way I can download this text and display it. I have opened the file with the native browser and its very quick but I don't want to use the native browser in my app.
Thanks

"...while reading the file in line by line the data is stored in an ArrayList String." Alternatively everything could be concatenated into a single string with line break characters added after every line. "...build a TableLayout with rows and textviews for each line." Alternatively a TextView can be a multi-line TextView and then only one of them is needed. But using a RecyclerView like in the answer might be a good idea to avoid the UI becoming sluggish. Then you'd store each line separately as you now do.

I had tried this as well ... as in each line is read  data+="\n"+strline. Still it was just as slow or not much better performance. using the recyclerView I get the results displayed in under 5 seconds. Just to add I was also getting outOfmemory exception when the files are too big. I didn't mention this in the question as I felt it irrelevant as I had a feeling the memory issue would be solved once I used a more efficient way of displaying the data.

You should use a RecyclerView for this. It will only inflate the TextViews that are currently needed, and recycles them, which drastically improves performance.
Add a RecycleView to your layout:
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/loggingRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Then, you need to define in a layout file how each single item of the RecyclerView should look like, similar to this text_row_item.xml file:
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/element_text"/>
</FrameLayout>

Next, define an adapter class which maps the input data to the individual RecyclerView items:
class CustomAdapter(private val logLines: Array<String>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
     * (custom ViewHolder)
     */
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView

        init {
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.logLine)
        }
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, viewGroup, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
        viewHolder.textView.text = logLines[position]
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = logLines.size

}

Finally, assign the adapter to the RecyclerView in your layout like this:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val logData = arrayOf("Log Statement 1", "Log Statement 2", "Log Statement 3")
        val customAdapter = CustomAdapter(logData )

        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.loggingRecyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = customAdapter

    }
}


Thanks bro, this worked like magic!!! I had no idea what recycler view was!! Thanks you
